# Is there a way to plot two columns of a data frame in the same axis?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which consists of 3 colums: 'Date', 'Time' and 'Data'
I want to plot 'Date' and 'Time' and the X axis and 'Data' on the Y axis. So far, since I used pandas to import my data set, I tried with:

```
df.plot(x= "Date", y="Data")
```

but I think it only allows one argument in 'x='

I also wonder if in this case, is better to define 'Date' and 'Time' as a single column

Thank you for your support!

Comment: What is the difference between Date and Time in your data?

Comment: Why do you need them in the same axis? IMO this would be confusing as they represent different units (i.e. days vs mins). Regardless, have you thought about re-scaling dates to timestamps? (i.e. 7/Apr/2022 --> 2022-04-07 00:00:00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new column called "DateTime" that combines "Date" and "Time".

Then plot it on the x axis and "Data" on the y axis:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = ...

df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str) + df['Time'].astype(str), format="%m-%d-%Y%H:%M:%S")
df.plot(x="DateTime", y="Data")
```